# Match start of the line

Tags: javacc

I am trying to match `***`, but I find that javacc matches `***` anywhere in the line. How do I make sure that it only matches `***` when there are no other characters other than spaces or tabs before `***` ? This is what I currently have

```
< HORIZONTAL_RULE: <ZERO_OR_MORE_OF_TAB_OR_SPACE> ("**")("*")+>
| <#ZERO_OR_MORE_OF_TAB_OR_SPACE: (" " | "\t")*>
```

But again, this matches any `***` prepended by zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lexical states. Use the DEFAULT state for the start of a line.

```
// Note that states do not apply to private regular expression definitions.
TOKEN: <#ZERO_OR_MORE_OF_TAB_OR_SPACE: (" " | "\t")*>

<DEFAULT> TOKEN: {
    <HORIZONTAL_RULE: <ZERO_OR_MORE_OF_TAB_OR_SPACE> ("**")("*")+ > : MIDLINE
}
<DEFAULT, MIDLINE> SKIP { <OTHERCHAR: ~["\n","\r"]> : MIDLINE }
<DEFAULT, MIDLINE> SKIP { <NEWLINE: "\n" | "\n\r" | "\r" | "\r\n"> : DEFAULT }
```

Comment: Quick question, this statement has me lost. Could you throw some more light please. `Note that states do not apply to private regular expression definitions.`

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to thankyou first, SO doesn't let me edit the comment now. But, thankyou.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just trying to explain why I didn't associate any lexical state with the ZERO_OR_MORE_OF_TAB_OR_SPACE production.